# images are returning from response, but cannot be seen

Tags: html, reactjs, web-services, nginx, flask

This is very confusing to me... I have a bunch of parallel folder structures that hold a bunch of gifs in them. An older folder (that I've been using as my test case) serves the gifs to the front end properly. But the parallel folders are not.

The response of the images are coming back with a 200 status code, so they do not appear as 'broken' images. I'm not really sure what to do next to try and debug.

Here are a few side-by-side comparisons of the two. The images are the LEFT are the ones that are embedding in the webpage correctly. The most obvious thing in the first image below is the 'Content Encoding' and the 'Content Type'. Is it not getting unzipped?

[image]

[image]

[image]

A few other points that may (or may not) matter:

- I am using nginx
- Nginx is server the React FE in one config
- Nginx is serving a separate api/backend that is Python/Flask
- I think (?) the images are being served by the first Nginx config.

Since all the gifs are named the same thing (though in different folders), maybe it's a weird caching issue?

Let me know what other helpful info I can provide.

Comment: Are you using webpack (with url-loader)?

Comment: @eshunsharma I'm using create-react-app and it's built in `build`. I didn't think it would 'see' the images though, and wouldn't build... But I could be wrong. Ideally, the images need to be fetched from the location every load. They are dynamic and can't be part of the build.

Comment: Why I asked you that is because there is a certain size limit set in url-loader. So like if your image is less than 10kbs it would load but if its more than that it may not load. I am not sure if that's the issue here but you may want to check it once.